# How to break up a large MySQL query and cache data with AJAX?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, timeout

I am using [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) to create PDF documents on the fly.  Some of the queries to generate these PDFs contain over 1,000+ records and my server is timing out with larger queries (Internal Server Error).  I am using PHP and MySQL.

How do I parse a large MySQL query with AJAX into smaller chunks, cache the data, and the recombine the results, in order to prevent the server from timing out?

Here is my current code:

```
require_once('../../libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF();

$prows = fetch_data($id);

$filename = '../../pdf_template.php';

foreach ($prows AS $row) {

    $pdf->AddPage('P', 'Letter'); 
    ob_start(); 

    require($filename);

    $html .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '')

}

$pdf->Output('documents.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: Can you run this as a scheduled mysql job/event instead?

Comment: @DavidCheung do you mean through a Cron Job?  No, this needs to be generated based on a user's action.

Answer (score 0):

If it is absolutely imperative that the data be generated *every* time that this gets called, you could chunk the query into blocks of 100 rows, caching the data on the filesystem (or, much better, in APC/WinCache/XCache/MemCache) then on the final AJAX call, (Finalquery=true), loading the cache, generating the PDF, and clearing the cache.

I'm assuming that you can't change the max run time of the script like `<?php set_time_limit(0);`

The flow would go like this:

- Generate a unique ID for the query action
- on the client side, get the maximum number of rows through the initial call to the php script (select count...etc).
- Then, divide it by 10, 100, 1000, however many requests you want to separate it into.
- Run an AJAX request for each one of these chunks (rows 0, 100, 100,200) with the unique id.
- On the server side, you select that number/selection of rows, and put it into a store somewhere. I'm familiar with WinCache (I'm stuck developing PHP on Windows...), so add it to the usercache: `wincache_ucache_add( $uniqueId . '.chunk' . $chunkNumber, $rows);`
- In the meantime, on the client side, track all the AJAX requests. When each one is finished, make a call to the generate PDF function serverside. Give the number of chunks and the unique id.
- On the server side, grab everything from the cache. `$rows = array_merge( wincache_ucache_get($uniqueId . '.chunk'. $chunkNumber1), wincache_ucache_get($uniqueId . '.chunk'. $chunkNumber2) );`
- Clear the cache: `wincache_ucache_clear();`
- Generate the PDF and return it.

Note that you really should just cache the query results in general, either manually or through functionality in an abstraction layer or ORM.

Comment: I can't change the max run time.  The principal of what you're describing sounds like it will work; however, still a little confused as to how I'd "cache the data on the filesystem".  Can you describe in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple cache like PEAR cache_lite. During a slow or off period, you can create a utility program to run and cache all the records you would need. Then when the user requests the PDF you can access your cache data without having to hit your database. In addition, you can just use the timestamp field on your table and request database records that have changed since the data was cached, this will significantly lower the current record count you are having to retrieve from the database in real time.

```
<?php
include 'Cache/Lite/Output.php';
$options = array(
    'cacheDir' => '/tmp/cache/',
    'lifeTime' => 3600,
    'pearErrorMode' => CACHE_LITE_ERROR_DIE,
    'automaticSerialization' => true
);

$cache = new Cache_Lite_Output($options);
if( $data_array = $cache->get('some_data_id') ) {
    $prows = $data_array;
} else {
    $prows = fetch_data($id);
    $cache->save($prows);
}

print_r($prows);

?>
```